# None of the functions of my android app work

Tags: android, sql, kotlin, android-room

I am new to android programming and am currently taking a course on developing an application To Do List on the MVVM architecture.
At this stage (according to the course), the functions of sorting tasks (by date of creation and by name), as well as the functionality of hiding the completed task, were implemented. However, none of these functions work for me. At the same time, no errors are shown when compiling the program and during operation.

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class TasksFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_tasks) {

    private val viewModel: TasksViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val binding = FragmentTasksBinding.bind(view)

        val tasksAdapter = TasksAdapter()

        binding.apply {
              recyclerViewTasks.apply {
                  adapter = tasksAdapter
                  layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
                  setHasFixedSize(true)
              }
            }
        viewModel.tasks.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            tasksAdapter.submitList(it)
        }

        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_fragment_tasks, menu)

        val searchitem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
        val searchView = searchitem.actionView as SearchView

        searchView.onQueryTextChanged {
            viewModel.searchQuery.value = it
        }
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when(item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_sort_by_name -> {
                viewModel.sortOrder.value = SortOrder.BY_NAME
               true
            }
            R.id.action_sort_by_date_created -> {
                viewModel.sortOrder.value = SortOrder.BY_DATE
                true
            }
            R.id.action_hide_completed_tasks -> {

                item.isChecked = !item.isChecked
                viewModel.hideCompleted.value = item.isChecked
                true
            }
            R.id.action_delete_all_completed_tasks -> {
                true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
```

And this is my DAO interface:

```
@Dao
interface TaskDao {

    fun getTasks(query: String, sortOrder: SortOrder, hideCompleted: Boolean): Flow<List<Task>> =
        when (sortOrder) {
            SortOrder.BY_NAME -> getTasksSortedByName(query, hideCompleted)
            SortOrder.BY_DATE -> getTasksSortedByDateCreated(query, hideCompleted)
        }


    @Query("SELECT * FROM task_table WHERE (isCompleted != :hideCompleted OR isCompleted = 0) AND name LIKE '%' || :searchQuery || '%' ORDER BY isImportant DESC, name")
    fun getTasksSortedByName(searchQuery: String, hideCompleted: Boolean): Flow<List<Task>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM task_table WHERE (isCompleted != :hideCompleted OR isCompleted = 0) AND name LIKE '%' || :searchQuery || '%' ORDER BY isImportant DESC, createdDate")
    fun getTasksSortedByDateCreated(searchQuery: String, hideCompleted: Boolean): Flow<List<Task>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(task: Task)

    @Update
    suspend fun update(task: Task)

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(task: Task)
}
```

And this is mine TaskViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class TasksViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val taskDao: TaskDao
    ) : ViewModel() {

    val searchQuery = MutableStateFlow("")

    val sortOrder = MutableStateFlow(SortOrder.BY_DATE)

    val hideCompleted = MutableStateFlow(false)


    private val taskFlow = combine(
        searchQuery,
        sortOrder,
        hideCompleted
    ) {
        query, sortOrder, hideCompleted ->
        Triple(query, sortOrder, hideCompleted)
    }.flatMapConcat { (query, sortOrder, hideCompleted) ->
        taskDao.getTasks(query, sortOrder, hideCompleted)
    }

    val tasks = taskFlow.asLiveData()

}

enum class SortOrder { BY_NAME, BY_DATE }
```

Will glad to ask for questions and be very thankful for help.

Comment: "Not working" is not a well-defined issue. Try debugging your code, step through it and figure out which part of your code is not behaving correctly. You could also post the Viewmodel code for better analysis.

Comment: Thanks! I see that I should try to debug, find the place which incorrect and so on, but I don't know where to start. It seems everything fine, except no functionality. And I added code u adviced me to add.

Comment: There's a lot to it, but it's a critical basic skill. https://developer.android.com/studio/debug In this case, you'll want to set breakpoints in your code to see if code is getting called when you expect it to be called.